# EasyTable NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on an Spring Boot application in which I would like to create a pdf when the user presses a button. I'm using apache.pdfbox and [vandeseer.easytable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable) in order to generate the PDF. So far so good.

But when I hit the button to generate the PDF (see the function below), it just gives me an "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vandeseer/easytable/structure/Table" for where I start building the table ("Table.TableBuilder myTable....).

Have I missed something in implementing easyTable? Generating an empty PDF was working before I added in easyTable...

```
public class pdfGeneration {

    // Where we actually want to generate and print the receipt
    public static void generatePDF(Cart cart) throws IOException {

        // Creating the document and an empty page
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        // Build the table
        Table.TableBuilder myTable = Table.builder()
                .addColumnsOfWidth(100, 50, 50)
                .fontSize(8)
                .borderColor(Color.RED);

        myTable.addRow(Row.builder()
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Productname").build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Quantity").build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text("Price").build())
                .build());


        // Close the contentStream, save and close the document
        contentStream.close();
        document.save("C:/Users/yourusername/Desktop/my_doc.pdf");
        document.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
    <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm so embarrased. I added that config at some point of course, but appearently it got lost in some merge conflict. I didn't thought about checking until your reply, that's now solved. Great thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries.  It happens to the best of us